# What's the different between -L/libpath and /etc/ld.so.conf configure the libpath that compiling in gcc/g++

Tags: linux, g++

I compiling my code,  but failed.

```
# g++ -g test.cpp -o test -lboost_filesystem                                  
/tmp/cc5yybJZ.o(.text+0xb0): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/tmp/cc5yybJZ.o(.text+0xbc):/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/tmp/cc5yybJZ.o(.text+0xc8):/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cc5yybJZ.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost10filesystem9file_sizeERKNS0_4pathE+0x19): In function `boost::filesystem::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:447: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but it was success when I compile with -L/usr/local/lib

```
g++ -g test.cpp -o test -lboost_filesystem -L/usr/local/lib
```

and the `/usr/local/lib` has already configured in `/etc/ld.so.conf`

```
# cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib64
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/mpc/lib
/usr/local/mpfc/lib
```

What's the reason? 
What's the different between -L/libpath and /etc/ld.so.conf configure the libpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/ld.so.conf` is used by the dynamic linker (see manpage `ld.so(8)`) to figure out which paths to search for your library file. This happens at runtime.

You still need to pass `-L/usr/local/lib` to `gcc`, which will pass it on to `ld` (see manpage `ld(1)`). This happens at compile time.

Why doesn't `gcc` or `ld` just look up the paths in `/etc/ld.so.conf` automatically? I'd guess a few possible reasons: (1) having more automatic behavior like this makes the system more complex and trickier to understand; (2) `gcc` runs on systems with different dynamic linkers (or none at all); (3) maybe that behavior is not what you wanted, and then you'd need some extra way to turn it off.

In any case, on most Linux systems, you would just have a package manager that puts the libraries in the right place (typically `/usr/lib`), so this is usually a non-issue. Otherwise, it's customary to just define your own `CFLAGS` variable to include the necessary `-L...` directives.

It's also possible to configure `gcc` to automatically pass various `-L...` directives (among other things) by modifying the [spec file](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Spec-Files.html).

Answer (score 2):

/etc/ld.so.conf is a runtime thing - it allows Linux to find the shared libraries your executables need to run.

You can augment /etc/ld.so.conf by defining $LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your environment.

"-L", on the other hand, is entirely for linking your program.  It's an "ld" thing.  Specifying "-L" in your g++ command should fix your link error.

You can use the "ldd" command to see what shared libraries a binary needs, and where in the environment it expects to find them.